# Error code:-2147024809 (80070057) "Cound not find specific object"

Tags: object

I keep getting this error for some code I am adapting. I have used this in other workbooks without issue as shown.  The line "Me.Controls("Reg" & X).Value = findvalue" is where I am getting stuck.  I use this throughout my project again without issue in other projects. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub lstLookup_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
'Search new and existing training and return data to user controls at the bottom of the form
'declare the variables
    Dim ID As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim findvalue
'error block
    On Error GoTo errHandler:
'get the select value from the listbox
    For I = 0 To lstLookup.ListCount - 1
        If lstLookup.Selected(I) = True Then
'set the listbox column
            ID = lstLookup.List(I, 8)
        End If
    Next I
'find the value in the range
    Set findvalue = Sheet2.Range("J:J").Find(What:=ID, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, -8)
'add the values to the userform controls
    cNum = 9
    For X = 1 To cNum
   **Me.Controls("Reg" & X).Value = findvalue**
     Set findvalue = findvalue.Offset(0, 1)
    Next
'disable controls force user to select option
'error block
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub 
errHandler::
    MsgBox "An Error has Occurred  " & vbCrLf & "The error number is:  " _
           & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
           "Please notify the administrator"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this any language in particular?

Comment: VBA, if that's what you are asking?